# New caching and deferred evaluation strategy

Tags: c#, locking

This is a simple wrapper class for a lambda expression, that stores one as `Expression` and hands it back out either as `Expression`, or compiled as `Func`. This is useful because while Linq-to-Objects requires a `Func`, other technologies such as Entity Framework require an `Expression` (so that the expression tree can be projected into SQL, which isn't feasible with the compiled `Func`). However, it would be nice if the compilation overhead of the `Func` were not taken until use, since it might never be used. (There doesn't appear to be a way to get true compile-time coercion to both types as the compiler can only make one inference about which form you want, expression or func.)

Here's an example of how it's used.

Given an object:

```
public partial class MyObject {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

That is represented in the database like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyObjects (
    Value int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MyObjects PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```

Then it works like this:

```
var greaterThan5 = new WhereConstraint<MyObject>(o => o.Value > 5);

// Linq to Objects
List<MyObject> list = GetObjectsList();
var filteredList = list.Where(greaterThan5).ToList(); // no special handling

// Linq to Entities
IQueryable<MyObject> myObjects = new MyObjectsContext().MyObjects;
var filteredList2 = myObjects.Where(greaterThan5).ToList(); // no special handling
```

If implicit conversion isn't suitable, you can cast explicitly to the target type, or more clearly, use one of the `AsExpression()` or `AsFunc()` methods.

```
var expression = (Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>) greaterThan5;
var func = greaterThan5.AsFunc();
```

Some additional thought on this has yielded a couple more points I think are worth adding:

- I do think that locking is required because I don't know enough about how variable assignment works, and so to be conservative I have to allow the possibility that without the lock, the `_funcGetter =` line could result in a state where a multithreaded application could attempt to execute it while it's still being assigned and there is an interim neither-fully-assigned-nor-unassigned state.
- If two threads did perform the `_funcGetter` function at a very close time, it's possible that the expression could be compiled twice (the lambda containing `lock` having started executing in both, but had not `lock`ing in both), but this *shouldn't* have deleterious side effects since everything would still work correctly.

Instead of checking whether a local variable is null, then locking when it is, then computing the value, and then on every call still checking if the variable is null and returning the cached value, what do you think of the following pattern (where the value is stored instead as a delegate that rewrites "itself")?

```
public class VersatileLambda<T> where T : class {
    private readonly Expression<T> _expression;
    private Func<T> _funcGetter;

    public VersatileLambda(Expression<T> expression) {
        if (expression == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }
        _expression = expression;
        _funcGetter = () => {
            lock (this) {
                var func = _expression.Compile();
                _funcGetter = () => func;
                return func;
            }
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator Expression<T>(VersatileLambda<T> lambda) {
        return lambda?._expression;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(VersatileLambda<T> lambda) {
        return lambda?._funcGetter();
    }

    public Expression<T> AsExpression() { return this; }
    public T AsLambda() { return this; }
}

public class WhereConstraint<[DelegateConstraint] T> : VersatileLambda<Func<T, bool>> {
    public WhereConstraint(Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda)
        : base(lambda) { }
}
```

Are there holes in this? Is the `lock` even necessary? (I suspect that it is but couldn't make a solid objective case why.) Is this a good strategy to use that other programmers will understand? Is avoiding a `null` check even worth this perhaps greater level of obfuscation?

Finally, I did check that the `this` reference points to the `VersatileLambda` class. But is there a way to get the `this` of a delegate from within it?

Note: use of Fody.ExtraConstraints and `[DelegateConstraint]` can get the same effect as (not yet available in C#) `where T : Delegate`.

Comment: would you mind to add an example of this in action?

Comment: Sure, I've added an explanation and example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the point of the code so I might be missing the mark but...

Your `_funcGetter` would make far more sense as a `Lazy<T>`

```
private readonly Expression<T> _expression;
private Lazy<T> _func;

public VersatileLambda(Expression<T> expression) {
    if (expression == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
    }
    _expression = expression;
    _func = new Lazy<T>(() => expression.Compile());
}

public static implicit operator T(VersatileLambda<T> lambda) {
    return lambda?._func.Value;
}
```

`Lazy` will handle all the thread safety issues for you. You don't need to worry about locking at all - the default will ensure only one is created (i.e. compile only called once).

As an aside - you should never `lock (this)` when `this` is public instance... you have no idea whether or not someone else will try to lock the instance and cause a deadlock. Always use a private object to synchronise access.

(code from memory directly into browser so might not compile but should be substantially correct)

*updated to use `Lazy<T>` as per comments.

Comment: I was staring at the code just 60 seconds ago thinking, "You know, I could abstract this into a class to do this work for me ... wait a minute, there already *is* such a thing. A Lazy!"

Comment: @ErikE - we've all done it :)

Comment: In this case it is `Lazy<T>` not `Lazy<Func<T>>`. And now `_func` can be `readonly`.